# Thread crash on multiplying 2 floats in swift

Tags: macos, swift

So I'm building a typing program and a user has the ability to add a lesson. Now as they're adding their lesson I have a "lesson length calculator" you put in your preferred WPM (default 40) and your preferred time to complete (default 2 minutes), it then calculates how many characters you're allowed to have and displays several other metrics to help you build your lesson as efficiently as possible.

My belief is that this is a bug in swift 1.2 but I wanted to ask here in case there was something obvious I was missing. I have a text field where you can type your preferred WPM, if you type a number in this text field there are no issues, if you type a letter however, the program crashes.

This gets very weird if you consider the following code.

```
infix operator =~ {}
var match :NSTextCheckingResult! = NSTextCheckingResult()
func =~ (input: String, pattern: String) -> Bool
{
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern:pattern, options:nil, error:nil)!
    var matches = regex.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(input))) as! Array<NSTextCheckingResult>
    match = regex.firstMatchInString(input, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(input)))
    if (matches.count > 0)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}

public func calculateAddLessonMetrics()
{
    //300 WPM is the average reading speed of a sighted person.
    //400 WPM average speed with VO.
    //125 WPM average braille reading speed.
    //(WPM * ((minutes * 60+seconds) / 60)) * 5 = number of chars you can use
    var preferredWPM:Float
    if (preferredWPMTextField.stringValue ~= "^(\\d+)$")
    {
        preferredWPM = (preferredWPMTextField.stringValue as NSString).floatValue
    }
    else
    {
        preferredWPM = 40.00
        println("Not a number")
    }
    preferredWPMTextField.stringValue = "\(preferredWPM)";
    var totalSeconds:Float
    if (preferredTimeTextField.stringValue ~= "^(\\d+):(\\d+)$")
    {
        var tempArray:NSArray = preferredTimeTextField.stringValue.componentsSeparatedByString(":");
        totalSeconds = (tempArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString).floatValue * 60
        totalSeconds += (tempArray.objectAtIndex(1) as! NSString).floatValue
    }
    else
    {
        totalSeconds = 120
        var minutes  = totalSeconds / 60
        preferredTimeTextField.stringValue = "\(Int(minutes)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((minutes*60) % 60))
    }
    var preferredTime:Float                        = totalSeconds / 60
    println("preferredWPM = \(preferredWPM) : preferredTime = \(preferredTime)");
    var maximumChars:Float                         = Float(preferredWPM) * preferredTime
    maximumChars                                   = maximumChars * 5
    var totalLength = 0;
    totalLength += count(addLessonObjectTextField.stringValue)
    if (temporaryLesson.count > 0)
    {
        for (var i:Int = 0; i < temporaryLesson.count;i++)
        {
            totalLength += count(temporaryLesson.objectAtIndex(i) as! String)
        }
    }
    var currentChars:Float                         = Float(totalLength) //what they're typing + what they've typed
    var currentWords:Float                         = currentChars / 5
    var requiredMinimumWPM:Float                   = currentWords / preferredTime
    var averageReadingTime:Float                   = currentWords / 300 //minute decimal
    var averageReadingTimeWithVoiceOver:Float      = currentWords / 400 //minute decimal
    var averageReadingTimeWithBrailleDisplay:Float = currentWords / 125 //minute decimal
    var lessonTime:Float                           = currentWords / Float(preferredWPM)
    var totalLessonTime:Float                      = lessonTime + averageReadingTime //minute decimal
    var totalLessonTimeWithVoiceOver:Float         = lessonTime + averageReadingTimeWithVoiceOver //minute decimal
    var totalLessonTimeWithBrailleDisplay:Float    = lessonTime + averageReadingTimeWithBrailleDisplay //minute decimal
    maximumCharactersTextField.stringValue         = "\(maximumChars)"
    currentCharactersTextField.stringValue         = "\(currentChars)"
    requiredWPMTextField.stringValue               = "\(requiredMinimumWPM)"
    readingTimeTextField.stringValue               = "\(Int(averageReadingTime)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((averageReadingTime*60) % 60));
    readingTimeVOTextField.stringValue             = "\(Int(averageReadingTimeWithVoiceOver)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((averageReadingTimeWithVoiceOver*60) % 60));
    readingTimeBrailleTextField.stringValue        = "\(Int(averageReadingTimeWithBrailleDisplay)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((averageReadingTimeWithBrailleDisplay*60) % 60));
    totalTimeTextField.stringValue                 = "\(Int(totalLessonTime)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((totalLessonTime*60) % 60));
    totalTimeVOTextField.stringValue               = "\(Int(totalLessonTimeWithVoiceOver)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((totalLessonTimeWithVoiceOver*60) % 60));
    totalTimeBrailleTextField.stringValue          = "\(Int(totalLessonTimeWithBrailleDisplay)):" + String(format: "%02d", Int((totalLessonTimeWithBrailleDisplay*60) % 60));
}
```

If I type a letter into the preferredWPMTextField the log shows:

```
Not a number
preferredWPM = 40.0 : preferredTime = 2.0
```

Then the thread crashes on this line:

```
        var maximumChars:Float = preferredWPM * preferredTime
```

With the insanely helpful error of:

```
Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1
```

Again if I type a number it works fine,

Comment: Are you sure you don’t just have a breakpoint? search for a blue triangle in front of (on top of) your rule numbers

Comment: Seems ridiculous that I missed that, I'm not sure I understand why it was working some of the time but you've solved my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error’s Containing `breakpoint` might indicate the use of a (unintentional) `breakpoint`

[image: breakpoint]

You can disable them by left-clicking again.
If you want to delete the `breakpoint` you can right-click and select delete.
A breakpoint will stop (or pause) your code, this can be very useful for debugging situations.